# Mandatory file apdu error: 6283 upon read. File invalidated

Tags: smartcard, javacard, apdu

I'm attempting to read EF_LOCI(Location Information) file from a USIM.

1.I'm selecting the MF

```
->00A40004023F00      
<-622C8202782183023F00A50980017183040001575B8A01058B032F0602C6099001408301018301818104000201069000
```

2.Now selecting DF TELECOM

```
->00A40004027F20
<-622C8202782183027F20A50980017183040001575B8A01058B032F0602C6099001408301018301818104000006DF9000
```

3.Finally select the EF_LOCI file:

```
->00A40004026F7E   
<-6283
```

The result is 6283 for some sims. According to the documentation it means the file is 'invalidated'. Which means what exactly?

Comment: What code/software are you using to read/write? Please provide more info. On what baseband processor?

Comment: I'm using a custom baseband soure code over Qualcomm chipset(You need to be their partnet for that). Its not something available for the average android developer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Means, A file will not be longer available for any function except for the SELECT and the REHABILITATE functions unless the file status of the EF indicates that READ and UPDATE may also be performed (that will be set during the EF Creation). File could be Invalidate because of Many reason. For Detail Please refer http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/11_series/11.11/1111-8e0.zip (annex C).

Comment: Agree. One of the reason is to lock the card using FDN / BDN mode, e.g. user have to activate the card using registration menu/SMS/dialing specific number.

Comment: @skoperst: Do u want to ask any thing else w.r.t. Invalidate ?

Comment: Got it. David thanks also, its really about FDN mode.

Answer (score 0):

If the SIM supports the FDN feature (FDN allocated and activated) a special mechanism shall exist in the SIM which invalidates both `EF_IMSI` and `EF_LOCI` once during each GSM session.This mechanism shall be invoked by the SIM automatically if FDN is enabled.

I think this is the reason why, when you try to select `EF_LOCI`, then the result is `SW 0x6283` (File_Invalidated).

Hope this will help you.